# how to destroy service?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a  wifi broadcastreciever , like this :

```
Intent in = new Intent(context, WifiChangeService.class);
    in.putExtra("bssid", wi.getBSSID());
    context.startService(in);
```

and  service (wifichangeservice ) , like this :

```
public class WifiChageService extends Service {



@Override
public void onCreate() {
   //here i want to test if bssid=="Home Network" , if it's equal i want to do "something"
    // then how can  I destroy or stop service , afer that "something" work is done
}
```

Comment: call **stopSelf()** in service to destroy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
   //here i want to test if bssid=="Home Network" , if it's equal i want to do "something"
    // then how can  I destroy or stop service , afer that "something" work is done
  if(yourbssid == netwokbssid){
     doYourStuff();
     stopSelf(); // also you can use onDestroy() directly
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void onDestroy()
{    
  Intent in = new Intent(context, WifiChangeService.class);
  context.stopService(in);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method to start and stop the services.

```
// Method to start the service
public void startService() {
     context.startService(new Intent(context, WifiChageService.class));
}

// Method to stop the service
public void stopService() {
     context.stopService(new Intent(context, WifiChageService.class));
}
```

Here i added the reference URL for you [Start and Stop Service](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm). Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks